# How to open new window in firefox with terminal on mac

Tags: macos, firefox, terminal

If I go to `cd /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS` and then run `./firefox -new-window http://google.com` it open a new version of firefox so I have to open at the same time, which is not what I want, I want it in the open firefox program. Then I tried with `open` it works to open new tabs, but I can't open a new window. If I run `open -a firefox -new-window http://google.com` It gives an error that -new-window is not a existing parameter.
So then I tried `open -a firefox --args -new-window http://google.com` but nothing happens it just swiches the focus of applictions to firefox. If I run `open -a firefox --args http://google.com`
 nothing happens again. When `open -a firefox --args -url http://google.com` does not work.
Recourses I have looked at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options
https://superuser.com/questions/277565/start-firefox-from-terminal-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be useful for you:

```
open -n /Applications/Firefox.app
```

The `-n` option allows open new window

Is possible that you are getting an error something like this: 
***"A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time"***

In that case is necessary delete the file `.parentlock`, you can find it in:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles
ls -l
cd <your profile>.default
rm -rf .parentlock
```

And try again: `open -n /Applications/Firefox.app`